# Javascript style identification

Tags: javascript

I need to identify applying styles using javascript. This much smiler what in Firebug. There i should identify inline or CSS base style which applying to give Text.

Is there any good example for this kind of work?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're after is a Javascript based version of Firebug then you can use [FirebugLite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). If you just want to programmatically find the styles for an element you might be able to hook your own Javascript code into it.